# How to keep the output window of the command line window open in vim?

Tags: vim, neovim

When I enter a command in neovim with `:` and then entering for example
`lua print(4)` and pressing Enter the command runs.

I want to keep this window open when I return the cursor to the file.
It closes automatically, how can I keep this Command Line Window output open?

[image]

Comment: 1. It's "command-line", not "Command Line Window". The "command-line window" is something else. 2. You can't keep it "open" the way you want. Use `:help :terminal` instead.